# Error handling in VBA with messagebox

Tags: vba

I am trying to handle wrong password when a user establishes a connection

```
Sub test ()
Connection.Open conString
If conString = Nothing Then
MsgBox "wrong password"
'exit application
End If
End Sub
```

But this code does not show the message box it fails before that

Comment: VBA has a mechanism to handle errors like that. Look at `On Error Goto ...`

Answer (score 1):

To bypass the default vba error handling, rewrite your code as the following:

```
Sub test ()
    On Error Resume Next
    Connection.Open conString
    if err.number <> 0 then msgbox "Connection Failed: " & err.description
End Sub
```

There are other Err properties and methods as well. Err.Raise(), Err.Source further information this at the Microsoft website -> [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf5ze0e%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)